# Extend Frames On Bezier Circle Path Animation

Tags: path, timeline

When putting an object to follow a path on a beizer circle. The frames it takes for a full 360 motion around the circle is 100 frames (from 1 frame to 101).

I was wondering if I could extend the frames to 201 for a full rotation. And how to go about doing this task.

Please and Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's quite possible, and (luckily) easy, too!

Select the *Bezier Circle*. Go to the *Properties panel > Object data tab > Path Animation dropdown* and change the *Frames:* value to 200.

[image]

Comment: Although timing wasn't mentioned in the OP, doesn't doubling the number of frames like that also make it take twice as long to complete the full 360 motion?

Comment: @HowardPautz Timing was the whole question. Read it again. Plus, they accepted it, so it must be right :)

Comment: oh, DUH, I fully misread it the other way round %-/ LOL  (-1 for my brain)

Comment: @HowardPautz Haha, it's cool. We all have those moments (at least I do!).